# How to implement @mentions on posts

Tags: php, javascript, post, twitter

I was wondering if you knew how I can use the @mentions like the ones on twitter and also, I mysql_real_escape_string the posts so how can I unescape the @ symbol?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you might want to have a look at regular expressions to replace `something` in `@something:` to a link or so.

Answer (score 3):

You have first to parse the messages before you escape it. When parsing, you have to replace the @mentions with whatever you want it (Userlink, Image, blah). After you changeed the message accordingly, you escape it and put it into the database.

Comment: how do I do that? How can I parse the @mention?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the twitter-text ruby library.  This is the library twitter uses to parse out @mentions, hashtags, and urls for display.  Obviously it's in ruby and that's not your language of choice, but you can at least look at the code to see how they are doing everything.  Here's the github link: <s>https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-rb</s> https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb

Twitter has apparently decided to start including a lot of this information as separate objects within an api result going into the future as well.  I haven't used the API in a few months myself, so I don't know what the status of this is, but you should check out the tweet entities page on the official documentation site: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities